# How do I rescale my gameobject to match with original gameobject?

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, scale

I have a grid of game objects in which I can change the number of game objects that fit inside the grid. The grid is a child of a game object. I wish to rescale all other grids to match my 4X4 grid size programmatically.

Desired size

[image: Desired size]

Grid to rescale

[image: Grid to rescale]

Each game object is 1 unit and the parent transform scale is (1,1,1). I know that if my grid is 8X8 that I would probably need to rescale to 0.5. I only have an issue in trying to calculate the rescale number.

Comment: Your grid seems to be 5x5, your target is 4x4 so do e.g. `currentSize / 5 * 4` so first normalize to a unit grid and scale it up .. or yes if it is 8x8 then `currentScale / 8 * 4` which would be a factor of `0.5f`

Comment: @derHugo You've been a huge help with my project. I actually did the calculation as ' (5 * 5) / (4 * 4) '

Comment: Ah yes obviously I ment for each side so yes you'll have to use squares

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So again as said it is pretty simple maths.

You have a grid with side length 5, you want 4.

So you normalize it via

```
currentSize / 5.0f * 4.0f
```

which would be a factor of `0.8f`.

Since you need to apply it to each side of your grid you share that so it has to be `0.8f * 0.8f` which is a factor of `0.16f`.

---

Or if you say it is 8x8 then the same calculations

```
currentSize / 8f * 4f
```

so a factor of `0.5`. then squared so `0.25f`.

Comment: Is the currentSize the scale?

Answer (score 0):

@derHugo Answer was good. For me, I answered my answer was:

```
    gridScaleratio = 1.0f / ((gridSize * gridSize) / (gridSize * 4.0f));
...
    playerGrid.transform.localScale = new Vector3(gridScaleratio, gridScaleratio, gridScaleratio);
```